# VBA what does * 1 mean when declaring a variable?

Tags: vba

I have seen VBA code that declares a variable like this

```
Dim name As String * 1
```

what does * 1 mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It designates the length of the string in characters. `String*n` is a fixed length string of `n` characters

Comment: What advantages are there to using this? Am I really forced to use mid() to grab a single char... and there is no clean way to get it working with a for each loop?

Comment: maybe you should include more code in question so it cam be answered fully.

Comment: Well I was just looking at a Tic-Tac-Toe game and they put an X and an O in this variable. I just thought it was funny looking as I never seen it before and it is funny that VBA lets you define the length of a string like an array when everywhere else it lacks the functionality of an array. Just a general programming question really.

Comment: I have only used it to pass arrays to `Fortran` which used fixed length arrays also. In your case `String*1` represents a single character since there is no `Character` object.

Comment: Ah that makes sense why the for each does not work on a string then because of the lack of a char type and thus forcing me to use the mid() method... it never hit me that VBA lacked a char type.